# Secure communication using encrypted messages

Tags: security, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

I have a question about how to encrypt messages between users. Note i will only talk about cryptography theory and not platform dependent code like C++ with Windows Cryptography. I am talking about system programming and not web programming encryption with TLS, SSL, etc...

**Also, ignore Certificates and Signing of messages, so just think of the Public keys as already being verified as not fraudulent and messages as being from the correct user.**

I believe the best way to reach fast and secure encryption communication between users is to have both users with a session key because symmetric encryption is faster than asymmetric, and using asymmetric encryption (RSA) for the secure transfer of the session key.

I know there are other key agreement algorithms like Diffie-Hellmans, but lets stick with RSA which is what i've chosen.

Please tell me if you see where this might be a insecure (man-in-the-middle attack) or drastically inefficient way of performing encrypted communications.

Theory steps:

i.) Parties = {Server, Client}

ii.) Server: Generate session key (RC4)

iii.) Client: Generate private/public key pair (RSA)

iv.) Client: Send public key to Server

v.) Server: Encrypt session key with Client's Public Key, then send encrypted 
session key to Client

vi.) Client: Decrypt session key using Client's Private Key

vii.) Both parties now hold the session key for fast encrypted communications

Server(Server's Session key) <--> Session Key's encrypted packet (Communication medium) <--> Client(Server's Session key, Client's Public/Private key pair)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Assumptions**:

- **Public Key Tampering is not possible**.

  - I think you mean this, by "ignore Certificates and Signing of messages"
- **Cryptosystem is not broken**.

  - Symmetric cipher is not broken (RC4 is broken, for example)
  - Asymmetric cipher is not broken
  - One-way Hash function is not broken
  - Random number generator is not broken

**Under these conditions, that's perfectly safe.** In fact what you described in your question is how PGP works.

[image]

If you are willing to learn more about attacks against PGP, go [here](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/vpns/attacks-pgp-users-perspective-1092).
And if you are willing to learn basics of cryptology, [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography) is an excellent beginner tutorial.

Comment: I changed from RC4 to DES which i believe is the best (most secure) symmetric algorithm available to me through the Windows Cryptography API. I think the Windows Cryptography library that im using covers most assumptions, like not including broken ciphers and using proper hashing, so thanks for confirming my theory!

Comment: DES is also broken, be careful :) Also, as symcbean mentioned in his/her answer, implementing your encryption is generally a very bad idea. You may want to see this post: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: You're right haha DES is poor. I changed again to AES-256. Can you tell me from this list which symmetric algorithm is the most secure? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375545(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @John Doe CALG_AES_256 is the strongest symmetric cipher in this list.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

> lets stick with RSA which is what i've chosen.

That's where your biggest vulnerability is.

Protocols such as TLS (which can use RSA) SSH and PGP provide a well defined mechanism for negotiating encryption, and implementations such as openssl provide a documented, tested, portable, robust and we'll tested abstraction layer.

Rolling your own solution carries massive risks of injecting vulnerabilities. And entails ongoing pain in maintenance.

BTW RC4 is considered broken by many people.